# Joomla Json Yandex Map

Tags: php, json, joomla, yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте, разбираюсь с созданием компонентов на joomla и столкнулся с проблемой.

Задача следующая. Вывести метки на Яндекс карту через objectManager, следовательно надо получать данные с сайта в формате JSON.

Для тестирования сделал view.josn.php (на скорую руку, потом уберу в контролер) 
Сам вывод: http://test.joomlazen.com/index.php?option=com_jz_location&view=ymap&format=json

Его код

```
class JZLocationViewYmap extends JViewLegacy {
public function getMapObject($data) {
    $item = new stdClass();
    $item->type = 'Feature';
    $item->id = $data->id;
    $item->geometry = new stdClass();
    $item->geometry->type = 'Point';
    $item->geometry->coordinates = '[55.831903,37.411961]';
    $item->properties = new stdClass();
    $item->properties->balloonContent = 'Content';
    $item->properties->clusterCaption = 'Cluste';
    $item->properties->hintContent = 'Hint';
    return $item;
    }
public function getMapFeatures() {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query
        ->select('*')
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__k2_items','a'))
        ->group($db->quoteName('a.id'))
        ->order('a.id DESC')
    ;
    $db->setQuery($query); 
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    if ($rows) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $main[] = $this->getMapObject($row);            
        }
        return $main;
    }
    return false;
}

public function display($tpl = NULL) {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $app->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $data = new stdClass();
    $data->type = "FeatureCollection";
    $data->features = $this->getMapFeatures();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

И соответственно создал вывод для удобства в простом html (Пример взял из Песочницы на сайте сделал Access-Control-Allow-Origin:"*" )

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Примеры. Добавление на карту большо числа объектов</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- Если вы используете API локально, то в URL ресурса необходимо указывать протокол в стандартном виде (http://...)-->
    <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://yandex.st/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.831903,37.411961],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
            clusterize: true,
            // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
            gridSize: 32
        });

    // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
    // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
    objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenDotIcon');
    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#greenClusterIcons');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://test.joomlazen.com/index.php?option=com_jz_location&view=ymap&format=json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
    });

}</script>
 <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Честно говоря с Ajax не сильно дружу. поэтому прошу помочь разобраться. Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему удалось решить путем  добавления контролера. 
Код контролера

```
class JZLocationControllerYmap extends JControllerForm {
 function __construct($config = array()) {
    parent::__construct( $config );

 }

 public function getMapObject($data) {
    $item = new stdClass();
    $item->type = 'Feature';
    $item->id = $data->id;
    $item->geometry = new stdClass();
    $item->geometry->type = 'Point';
    $item->geometry->coordinates = array(55.831903,37.411961);
    $item->properties = new stdClass();
    $item->properties->balloonContent = 'Content';
    $item->properties->clusterCaption = 'Cluste';
    $item->properties->hintContent = 'Hint';
    return $item;
    }
public function getMapFeatures() {
    $db = JFactory::getDbo(); 
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query
        ->select('*')
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__k2_items','a'))
        ->group($db->quoteName('a.id'))
        ->order('a.id DESC')
    ;
    $db->setQuery($query,'0','1000000'); 
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    if ($rows) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $main[] = $this->getMapObject($row);            
        }
        return $main;
    }
    return false;
}

public function some() {
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $app->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $data = new stdClass();
    $data->type = "FeatureCollection";
    $data->features = $this->getMapFeatures();
    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Так же была ошибка в координатах

```
$item->geometry->coordinates = '[55.831903,37.411961]';
```

Они должны быть массивом

```
    $item->geometry->coordinates = array(55.831903,37.411961);
```